# List files with line count and date

Tags: bash, shell, text-processing, ls, wc

I want to be able to list files showing the number of lines the each file has and the date. I can happily get the line count using `wc -l *`. Not a problem. I can get the date using `ls -l`.

Is there a way to combine the two commands to give me a single output in columns?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is something with `find` + `wc` + `date`.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -exec sh -c '[ -f "$0" ] && \
  printf "%6s\t\t%s\t%s\n" "$(wc -l<"$0")" "$(date -r "$0")" "$0"' {} \;
```

Instead of `date -r` one can also use for example `stat -c%y`.

The output looks like this:

```
   394      Thu Oct 16 22:38:14 UTC 2014    ./.zshrc
     7      Thu Oct 30 11:19:01 UTC 2014    ./tmp.txt
     2      Thu Oct 30 06:02:00 UTC 2014    ./tmp2.txt
    40      Thu Oct 30 04:16:30 UTC 2014    ./pp.txt
```

Using this as starting point one can create a function which accepts directory and pattern as parameters:

```
myls () { find "$1" -maxdepth 1 -name "$2" -exec sh -c '[ -f "$0" ] && \
  printf "%6s \t\t%s\t%s\n" "$(wc -l<"$0")" "$(date -r "$0")" "$0"' {} \;; }
```

After that `myls /tmp '*.png'` will list only images from `/tmp` (notice single quotes around pattern to prevent shell from expanding a glob operator `*`).

Comment: FYI, pay special attn to Jimmij's comment about using `stat -c%y`. You're running `date` on every file using the former command, `date -r`. Otherwise +1, this is a good solution to the Q.

Comment: Great answer. I changed date to `(date -r "$0" -%x)` to give me something to import into a spreadsheet. Exactly what I needed and later I'll have a look at this more in depth.

Comment: @JohnReid I've changed original post a little, removed unnecessary variables, and added function for patterns. You may want to take a look. @slm you are right that one can do `stat` and `wc` on the whole list `find ... {} +` (if this is what you are saying), yes that would be for sure faster, but on the other hand more complicated since one would need to deal with loop over arrays later on (at least as I see it).

Comment: @jimmij: Why not say `find -type f` instead of making the shell do the test?

Comment: @G-Man You are right, `-type f` would be simpler.

Answer (score 2):

The `find`-based solutions look the most elegant, but just for fun here are a couple of other ways to attack this.

This one uses `sed` & `head` to clean up the output of `wc`, then uses `join` to combine that to the output of `stat`, using the file name as the join field.

`pat="A*";join -1 2 -2 1 -t ' ' <(wc -l $pat|head -n-1|sed 's/^[ ]*//') <(stat -c '%n %y' $pat) | awk '{printf "%-20s %6s %s %s %s\n",$1,$2,$3,$4,$5}'`

And a simpler one that uses `paste`, with `awk` again tidying up the columns and also checking that the file names match.

`pat="A*";paste -d ' ' <(wc -l $pat) <(stat -c '%n %y' $pat) | awk '$2==$3{printf "%6s %s %s %s\n", $1, $4, $5, $2}'`

However, if the names *don't* match (IOW the file lists change while this command is running) then the errors are invisible. But this version reports the errors:

`pat="A*";paste -d ' ' <(wc -l $pat) <(stat -c '%n %y' $pat) | awk '$2==$3{printf "%6s %s %s %s\n", $1, $4, $5, $2;next};{print "Error:" $0}'`

Of course, that one will print an error message for the final line, but that's easy enough to fix. Or ignore. :)

Answer (score 0):

I used `awk` as shown below:

```
wc -l * | head --lines=-1 | while read num file
do
  echo -n $num" "
  ls -l $file | awk '{
     for (i=6; i <= NF; i++)
       printf $i " "
  }'
  echo
done
```

- `head` is used to remove the last line (total line of `wc` output).
- `num` contains the number of line of `file`.
- `awk` is used to print the time output from `ls -l` output.

Comment: (1) I realize that the question says "list files", but, if there's only one file in the directory, `wc` will not output a "total" line, and so the `head` will discard the line count of the one existing file. (2) This breaks if filenames contain newlines. (3) This breaks if filenames contain ***spaces,*** because you say `$file` instead of `"$file"`. You should always quote all shell variables references unless you have a good reason not to, and you’re sure you know what you’re doing.

Answer (score 0):

I used `xargs` with `find` :

```
find . -type f | xargs -i  sh -c 'echo -n `date -r {}`; \
     echo -n "    "; echo -n `wc -l {}`; echo '
```

Output:

```
Thu Oct 30 19:16:38 IST 2014    0 ./b
Thu Oct 30 19:16:38 IST 2014    0 ./a
Thu Oct 30 19:16:38 IST 2014    0 ./c
Thu Oct 30 19:16:56 IST 2014    10 ./testfile
```

Little formatting with `printf`  instead of `echo` as done by @jimmij:

```
find . -type f | xargs -i sh -c 'printf "%s\t%s\t\n" \
     "$(date -r {} +%x\ %H:%M:%S)" "$(wc -l {})" '
```

Answer (score -1):

What about :

```
ls -lrth yourfile|awk '{print $6 $7 " " $8 system("wc -l " $9) }' | tr '\n' ' '
```

Comment: Explain what this is doing and how it works!

Comment: Unfortunately wc dumps a new line which is being left behind.

Comment: I added tr to remove the "\n"

Comment: Ah I missed it, sorry. It's not working for a list of files now though as it removes all of the line breaks.

Comment: This seems so unnecessary given the `find` solution proposed above. This solution not only requires three actual commands, but it also uses a file on the system.

Comment: Why would you choose to use a temporary file when all you need to do is pipe the output of the `awk` into `tr`?